# Visual Studio 2010: How to replace all <%: Resources.A.B %>

Tags: visual-studio-2010, replace

Need help with Visual Studio 2010.

My problem:
I have millions

```
<%: Resources.A.B %>
```

all over in my aspx sites and I just want to change them all to

```
<%: Html.FormatResourceString(Resources.A.B) %>
```

Yes thats all ;-)
Please note:
I want to do it in Visual Studio 2010 and NOT at runtime!

Replacing

```
<%: Resources
```

with

```
<%: Html.FormatResourceString(Resources
```

is not the problem, the problem is the **")"** and the end.

How can this be made? 
How must the regular expression look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Find: `\<%\: Resources\.{.+} %\>`
- Replace with: `<%: Html.FormatResourceString(Resources.\1) %>`

You may also take a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). There are some nice examples at the end.

Comment: WOW! That was fast and works absolute perfect! Thank you very much!